# NodeJS file sharing server, like Dropbox or Google Drive

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, dropbox

I'm writing a term paper
I need to create a server for sharing and storing files (up to 10 MB for example) between users, something similar to the Dropbox / Google Drive. The server must be written on NodeJS, preferably with Express. I managed to save the files in the MongoDB ( because it's fast) using GridFS. But there are some questions:

1. If I organize a directory tree (which is something like emulation of a file system) as a separate tree, the endpoints of which are file's ID from GridFS, is this a good practice? What npm module should I use for this.
2. How to organize sending a file to a user from the database, because Now I need to create a data stream from the database, then write it in the response, and then send it to the user. Is there any way to ensure that the data is sent to the user by packages.

Comment: Kind of broad really. You might read up on [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) as a general concept.

Comment: @NeilLunn , what do u mean, should I store files locally, without DB?